# Redefinition of an existing Python function in a Cython pxd file

Tags: python, cython

I've got a function that's called in an inner loop so I want to use Cython to speed it up.

Adding type hints in a `.pxd` file helps, but replacing the implementation with a bit of C magic helps even more, so I tried to define the function in the pxd file and then replace it:

```
# test.py
import cython

def foo_():
    print('Hello world')

if not cython.compiled:
    foo = foo_
```

```
# test.pxd

# What I want:
# @cython.skipdefinition
# foo()


cdef inline void foo():
    print('Hello world from Cython')
```

And, of course, it fails: `test.py:7:4: Assignment to non-lvalue 'foo'` because C doesn't allow assigning to functions.

Is there a way to replace an existing Python function in a `pxd` file?

Answer (score 2):

There's at least a couple of options:

1. If you don't need to share the `cdef` function between multiple modules then you can put the whole thing in the .py file and not use the .pxd file. The `@cython.inline` decorator helps you here:

   ```
   import cython

   @cython.cfunc
   @cython.inline
   def foo():
       if cython.compiled:
           print("Hello world from Cython")
       else:
           print("Hello world")
   ```
2. If you *do* need the definition in a .pxd file to share it between multiple modules then you need to change the assignment. Write the pure Python version to the module `globals()` dict instead:

   ```
   # ... other code as you wrote it ...

   if not cython.compiled:
       globals()['foo'] = foo_
   ```

   From Cython's point of view this is not overriding a C name so it is fine.

I prefer option 1 if possible since the intent is clearer.

Comment: I didn't mention it, but there's bonus points for no dependency on Cython for the pure python solution. So, solution 2 could be written as  

``` 
try:
    from cython import compiled
except ImportError e:
    compiled = False
if not compiled:
    globals()['foo'] = foo_
```